# Different NPM package versions in different PCs

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I have an AngularJS project which uses NPM as a package manager. I have copies of this project in two different PCs (Ubuntu 16.0.4 OS).
When I run `npm ls` command in two PCs to check package versions, some of the packages give different versions.
How is this happening when package.json is same?
How to solve this issue?

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "~0.4.7",
    "aws-sign2": "~0.6.0",
    "bl": "~1.0.0",
    "caseless": "~0.11.0",
    "config-chain": "~1.1.9",
    "extend": "~3.0.0",
    "forever-agent": "~0.6.1",
    "form-data": "~0.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "~0.26.3",
    "har-validator": "~2.0.3",
    "hawk": "~3.1.2",
    "http-signature": "~1.1.0",
    "inherits": "~2.0.1",
    "ini": "~1.3.4",
    "is-typedarray": "~1.0.0",
    "json-stringify-safe": "~5.0.1",
    "kew": "~0.7.0",
    "mime-types": "~2.1.8",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "nopt": "~3.0.6",
    "npmconf": "~2.1.2",
    "once": "~1.3.3",
    "osenv": "~0.1.3",
    "qs": "~6.0.1",
    "request": "~2.67.0",
    "request-progress": "~0.4.0",
    "semver": "~5.1.0",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7",
    "source-map": "~0.5.3",
    "source-map-support": "~0.4.0",
    "stringstream": "0.0.5",
    "tough-cookie": "~2.2.1",
    "typescript": "1.7.5",
    "uid-number": "0.0.6",
    "which": "~1.2.0",
    "zeparser": "0.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower-nexus3-resolver": "~1.0.1",
    "browser-sync": "~2.7.12",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.2",
    "chalk": "~1.0.0",
    "concat-stream": "~1.5.0",
    "del": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.5.2",
    "gulp-csso": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-debug": "~3.1.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~2.0.2",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-inject": "~1.3.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.3",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.3",
    "gulp-rev": "~5.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
    "gulp-scss-lint": "~0.4.0",
    "gulp-size": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
    "gulp-tslint": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "~2.8.1",
    "gulp-typings": "~2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.0.5",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.0.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.36",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-sinon": "~1.0.4",
    "lodash": "~3.9.3",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.8.0",
    "merge-stream": "~0.1.7",
    "require-dir": "~0.3.0",
    "sinon": "~1.16.1",
    "typescript": "1.7.5",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Node versions are equal in both PCs

Comment: To resolve this issue consider: **1.** Generating a [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) for your project on one PC. This will create a file which describes the exact version tree of the dependencies and sub-dependencies used in your project. **2.** Then copy the updated project, (i.e. the one which has the new `package-lock.json` file), to your second PC and run a new `npm install`.